# Porting Javascript code to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anything which converts javascript code to jquery.

It will be like:

`Input:` Javascript code for example

```
var val = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
```

`Output:` Equivalent Jquery code

```
var val = $("#test").html();
```

`Function:`

```
function js2jq(javascript)
{
   //some code ****
   return jquery
}
```

Comment: Yep, Its you Mr. Furquan Khan

Comment: ohh really, but I need some tool, some plugin for doing it. It'll take me time to develop one.

Comment: You know that `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML` is 10 times faster than `$("#test").html();`? So what are you winning here?

Comment: Even if there was one, why in the world would you use it??

Comment: I'd rather prefere to write a function `jq2js(jquery)` ;-)